Almost all projections of the four corner Cantor set have $0$ Lebesgue measure. A mistake in the proof and how to fix it
Let $E$ be the $1/4$ Cantor set, which I define briefly here
$$E := \{ 3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\epsilon_n}{4^n} } \, : \, \epsilon_n = 0 \text{ or } 1\}$$
Or it can be defined in this way

Let $\mathcal{S}_1(A) := (1/4)A = \{ x/4 \, : x \in A\}$
$\mathcal{S}_2(A) := 3/4 + (1/4)A = \{ 3/4 + x/4 \, :  x \in A\}$
let $E_0 := [0,1]$ and $E_{n+1} := \mathcal{S}_1(E_{n}) \cup \mathcal{S}_2(E_n)$
then $E = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}{E_n}$

I want to show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ for which $\mathcal{L}^1(E + \lambda E) = 0$ for almost all $\lambda \in [0,\delta]$ where $\mathcal{L}^1$ denotes the 1 dimensional Lebesgue measure.
This is because I would like to show the existence of a Bescicovitch set in the following way :
Let $E_0 := \{ (-x/3,0) : x \in E\}$
$E_1 := \{(2x/3 , 1) : x \in E\}$
Let $F$ be the set of lines passing trough $E_0$ and $E_1$, which is
$$F := \{ (a + t(b-a),t) \, : \, t \in [0,1] \, , (a,0) \in E_0 \, , (b,1) \in E_1 \}$$
The set of $x/y$ angular coefficients of the unit segments passing through $E_0$ and $E_1$ is the set
$$\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{ \frac{\epsilon_n + 2{\epsilon'}_n}{4^n}} \, : \, \epsilon_n,\epsilon'_n = 0 \text{ or } 1 \}$$
But this is $[0,1]$, so adding 3 rotations of $F$ we find a Kakeya set.
The only thing I have to show is that $\mathcal{L}^2(F) = 0$.
I've looked at this paper TROIS NOTES SUR LES ENSEMBLES PARFAITS LINÉAIRES
I think in the paper $F$ is defined in a slightly different way but it's not an important different.
Now since $E = \mathcal{S}_1(E) \cup \mathcal{S}_2(E)$ we have that $E$ is made of two parts, similarly also $E_0$ and $E_1$ are made of two parts, therefore $F$ is made of four parts (look at the figure in the paper)
$F = F^{gg} \cup F^{gd} \cup F^{dg} \cup F^{dd}$ (g stands for "left" and d stands for "right"), where for example
$F^{gd}$ contains the segment with extrema lying on the left part of $E_0$ and the right part of $E_1$, the other sets are defined similarly.
The paper defines the notion of horizontal affinity, which is something like
$$\mathcal{HA}(A,\rho,a,b) := \{ (\rho x + (1-y)a + yb,y) \, : \, (x,y) \in A \}$$
and shows that for certain choices of $a_{\alpha \beta},b_{\alpha \beta}$ and with $\alpha,\beta = g \text{ or } d$
$$\mathcal{S}^{\alpha \beta}(A) := \mathcal{HA}(A,1/4,a_{\alpha \beta},b_{\alpha \beta})$$
One has
$$F^{\alpha \beta} = \mathcal{S}^{\alpha \beta}(F)$$
So from this it follows that
$$\mathcal{L}^2(F^{ g g} \cup F^{g d} \cup F^{d g} \cup F^{d d} ) = \mathcal{L}^2(F) = \mathcal{L}^2(F^{g g}) + \mathcal{L}^2(F^{g d}) +  \mathcal{L}^2(F^{d g}) + \mathcal{L}^2(F^{dd}) $$
So it follows $$\mathcal{L}^2(F^{g g} \cap F^{g d}) = \mathcal{L}^2(F^{d d} \cap F^{d g} ) = 0$$
And now in the paper it is claimed that by mapping $F^{g g}$ and $F^{d d}$ in $F$ via an horizontal affinity, the two sets $F^{g g} \cap F^{g d}$ and $F^{d d} \cap F^{d g}$ are mapped in two sets of which the union contains the set $\{ (x,y) \, : \, (x,y) \in F \: , \: y \leq \delta \}$ for some $\delta > 0$ (I think $\delta = 1/6$ but it's not important).
My problem is that I don't understand why this is true, in fact I think this is not true, this is because in the Book "Fourier Analysis and Hausdorff Dimension" by Mattila it is presented another proof (Peres-Simom-Solomyak proof of the projections of $C(1/4)$ ) which is much less elementary.
Therefore my question is : is it true or not? If it is how can I show it? If it isn't then does it exists a simpler argument than the on in the book by Mattila to show that $\mathcal{L}^2(F)= 0$ ?
Now I show how this is related to the first question :
By Fubini $\mathcal{L}^2(F) = 0$ if and only if $\mathcal{L}^1(F \cap \{y = t\}) = 0$ for almost all $t$
It turns out that $F \cap \{y = t\}$ is something like the set $E + \lambda E$, so we have
$\mathcal{L}^2(F) = 0$ if and only if $\mathcal{L}^1(E + \lambda E) = 0$ for almost all $\lambda > 0$
But now since
$$E + \lambda E = E + \lambda \mathcal{S}_1(E) \cup E + \lambda \mathcal{S}_2(E)$$
We find that
$\mathcal{L}^1(E+\lambda E) = 0$ if and only if $\mathcal{L}^1(E + \lambda/4 \, E) = 0$
Thus finally we have that for any $\delta > 0$
$$\mathcal{L}^2(F) = 0 \iff \mathcal{L}^1(E + \lambda E) \; \text{for almost all } \lambda \in [0,\delta]$$
